# Image preprocessing for egg marking recognition with Tesseract

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, google-vision

The goal is to make an app which can recognize egg markings, for example `0-DE-134461`. I tried both [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM#400-alpha-for-windows) and the [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) on the following images. The results from both OCR engines are disastrous.

[image: German Egg]
[image: Spanish Egg]

*0-DE-46042*

```
Tesseract → ""
Google Vision API → " 2 "
```

*3-ES08234-25591*

```
Tesseract → ""
Google Vision API → " Es1234-2SS ) R SHAH That is part "
```

---

## Cropped

I manually cropped the images with Photoshop.

[image: German Egg - Cropped]
[image: Spanish Egg - Cropped]

*0-DE-46042*

```
Tesseract → ""
Google Vision API → ""
```

*3-ES08234-25591*

```
Tesseract → "3ΓÇöE503ΓÇÿ234-gg"
Google Vision API → " -ESOT23-2559 ) "
```

---

## Thresholded

I color-selected the text on both eggs manually with Photoshop and removed the background.
[image: German Egg - Thresholded]
[image: Spanish Egg - Thresholded]

*0-DE-46042*

```
Tesseract → "OΓÇöDEΓÇö46042"
Google Vision API → " O-DE-46042 "
```

*3-ES08234-25591*

```
Tesseract → ""
Google Vision API → " 3-ESO8234-9 "
```

---

## Removing the circular warp?

I would assume that the last preprocessing step should be removing the circular warp, but I wouldn't know how to do that manually using Photoshop, let alone automating that.

---

## My questions

- Am I heading in the right direction?
- Are my preprocessing steps correct?
- What would be the approach to automate these steps in, say, OpenCV?

---

#### Extra info

The command I used to get the tesseract OCR results:

```
λ tesseract {egg_picture}.jpg --psm 7 stdout
```

The tesseract version:

```
λ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.0.0-alpha.20170804
 leptonica-1.74.4
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.0) : libpng 1.6.20 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.
```

Platform: `Windows 10`

---

#### Edit 1

I applied adaptive thresholding on some egg marking images with OpenCV. These are the results so far:

[image: IMG A (edit 1)]
[image: IMG C (edit 1)]
[image: IMG B (edit 1)]
[image: IMG H (edit 1)]
[image: IMG D (edit 1)]
[image: IMG E (edit 1)]
[image: IMG G (edit 1)]
[image: IMG I (edit 1)]

However, there's still lots of noise. I'm struggling to adjust the parameters so that it works well across different images.

---

Comment: yes, I think you'll have to correct the circular warp. For color thresholding I would try HSV color-space, but not sure whether the red (font) and the orange (egg) are far away enough...

Comment: For correcting the circular wrap you can apply homography. You just have to map points lying on a curved line to a line parallel to the top-left point(for upper surface, similarly you can do for bottom surface). Now detecting the points lying on a curved surface from a binary image should not be a difficult task

Comment: https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/how-machine-learning-with-tensorflow.html

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion.

I tried applying local histogram equalization for all the three channels in the BGR color space and then merged them.

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

With the details in the image more enhanced you can think about preprocessing on these images.

I also tried globally equalizing the histogram of the three channels separately. The images although clear than the original, lacked the depth in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the histogram equalization trick on the RGB channels. The eggcode definately stands out more. However, I've not been able to successfully binarize the text. Any idea?

Comment: I did not try anything yet. Try performing difference of gaussian with different kernel sizes or adaptive thresholding.

Comment: I've tried adaptive thresholding, but there's lots of binary noise. I've added images on the question of the results.